# Extract content after colon if only one : exists in string

Tags: .net, regex

I want to extract the content after the `:`, but there can be only one `:`.

Examples:

```
foo:bar             # match, extract 'bar'
foo:123             # match, extract '123'

foo:bar:123         # do not match
```

So that last example should not match because it has multiple `:`.

I tried a negative lookbehind `^.+(?<!:):(.+)$` but that nonetheless matches and extracts from that last example.

Here's [a demo](https://regex101.com/r/ptFfaO/1).

Comment: @bobblebubble Thanks for the rename, I think you saved this question... ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/G1Tgcx/1)):

```
^[^:]+:([^:]+)$
```

This will match only lines with one `:` and get the string after the `:`

Comment: I never thought to do it that way. It's weird with regex, because I know most of the rules, but one still needs to know the order in which to apply them! And the order is sometimes non-intuitive. Just need practice I suppose. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In C# you could also make use of lookbehind with an infinite quantifier to get a match only:

```
(?<=^[^:]*:)[^:]+$
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is to the left is

  - `^` Assert the start of the string
  - `[^:]*:` Match optional chars other than `:` followed by matching the `:`
- `)` Close the lookbehind
- `[^:]+` Match 1+ chars other than `:`
- `$` End of string

See a [.NET regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8JxWtz/1).

If you don't want to cross newlines:

```
(?<=^[^:\r\n]*:)[^:\r\n]+$
```

Comment: Thanks for this alternative. Is it a "c#-ism" that only works in the .net regex engine? Good enough for me, I'm just curious (there's all sorts of differences in the dotnet engine that I've encountered over time.)

Comment: @lonix This will work in Javascript when a [lookbehind is supported](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) like Chrome V8 engine, and it will also work using the [Python PyPi regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module.